# Convert Lighttpd rewrite to Nginx [new]

Tags: web, nginx, lighttpd

I've seen lots people asking about converting Lighttpd to Nginx but haven't seen my example in it's total form. If anyone could help, please!

I want to convert:

```
url.rewrite = (
            "^/includes/(.*)$" => "/includes/$1",
            "^/templates/(.*)$" => "/templates/$1",
            "^/css/(.*)$" => "/css/$1",
            "^/classes/(.*)$" => "/classes/$1",
            "" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

I tried using:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

But if I link directly to a resource, it displays it instead of rewriting back to index.php

I also wondered if this might work, but it doesn't seem to:

```
rewrite ^/includes/(.*)$ /includes/$1 break;
rewrite ^/classes/(.*)$ /classes/$1 break;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
E